# Problems updating countdown timer in UIAlertController

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I'm trying to update a countdown timer in the message part of a UIAlertController. I've tried lots of answers suggested on here but with no joy.
I have a simple ViewController to try out what I'm trying to achieve.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var counter:Int = 5
var timer: NSTimer?
var label = ""
var message = "in "

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    showAlert()
}

func showAlert(){
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Try again ", message: countDownString(), preferredStyle: .Alert)

    presentViewController(alertController, animated: true){
        self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: #selector(self.decrease), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
}

func decrease()
{
    var minutes: Int
    var seconds: Int
    if(counter > 0) {
        self.counter -= 1
        print(counter)  // Correct value in console
        minutes = (counter % 3600) / 60
        seconds = (counter % 3600) % 60
        label = String(format: "%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds)
        print(label)  // Correct value in console
    }
    else{
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        timer!.invalidate()
    }
}

func alertMessage() -> String {
    print(message+"\(self.label)")
    return(message+"\(self.label)")
}

func countDownString() -> String {
    print("\(counter) seconds")
    return "\(counter) seconds"
}
```

}

Counter and Label both show the correct values in the console but I'm unable to get them to display the values in the UIAlertController.
screenshots show the output i'm getting in the view controller.

Where am I going wrong?

[image: alertMessage screenshot]
[image: countDownString screenshot]

I'm using Xcode 7.3 and Swift 2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you instantiate your `UIAlertController` in the code below, current value from `countDownString()` is copied as message and cannot be updated this way

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Try again ", message: countDownString(), preferredStyle: .Alert)
```

You should store your `UIAlertController` as instance property, something like this:

```
var alertController: UIAlertController!
```

change your code for `showAlert()` to:

```
func showAlert(){
    alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Try again ", message: countDownString(), preferredStyle: .Alert)
    presentViewController(alertController, animated: true){
        self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: #selector(self.decrease), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
}
```

and update `alertController` message directly in your `decrease()` function:

```
func decrease()
{
    var minutes: Int
    var seconds: Int
    if(counter > 0) {
        self.counter -= 1
        print(counter)  // Correct value in console
        minutes = (counter % 3600) / 60
        seconds = (counter % 3600) % 60
        alertController.message = String(format: "%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds)
        print("\(minutes):\(seconds)")  // Correct value in console
    }
    else{
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        timer!.invalidate()
    }
}
```

Comment: same solution. but you beat me to it. :)

Comment: Excellent thank you works well. One small hiccup, it first displays 5 then 00:04, 00:03, etc. How would i change the initial variable to display 00:05 in keeping with the rest?

Comment: Or even not display the initial value?

Comment: Thanks again I've sorted the other hiccup. Thanks for your explanation of my errors. It helps greatly to have the answers with an explantation.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var timer:Timer?
    var timeLeft = 300

    timeLeft = 300
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(onTimerFires), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

  @objc func onTimerFires() {
       
        var minutes: Int
        var seconds: Int

        if timeLeft == 0 {
            timer?.invalidate()
        }
        timeLeft = timeLeft - 1
       // hours = timeLeft / 3600
        minutes = (timeLeft % 3600) / 60
        seconds = (timeLeft % 3600) % 60
        timeLabel.text = String(format: "%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds)
    }
```